# C++ write utf-8 to text file

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8

How to write characters in UTF-8 coding page into text file in С++?

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    ofstream fout("tree.txt");
    fout << "┌───────────────22───────┐" << endl;
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Wrong characters will be written into file.

Comment: If you want to ask questions in Russian then please use [ru.stackoverflow.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/),  questions on `stackoverflow.com` have to be in English.

Comment: @t.niese Translating a post by somebody who is not willing or not able to communicate in English is not helpful. It might result in effort being spent on a lost cause. If OP cannot express in English, then they will not be able to give feedback or clarifications.

Comment: @Yunnosch that's true.

Comment: and you must mark negative votes?

Comment: @ShahzodShafizod you don't know who cast the down-vote, could have been anyone. But down-vote was, no matter by whom, was justified as the question was not in English.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write UTF-8 literals, then you should encode the source file with UTF-8, and make sure that the compiler reads the input as UTF-8. If you've done that, then the output should be correct. You could use `u8"┌───────────────22───────┐"` literal just to be sure. Unfortunately, there's no `std::basic_ifstream<char8_t>` though.